# How to automatically insert text in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm wondering if there is a way to insert text just like short codes. For an example, whenever I typed %sitename, I want it to automatically get the predefined site name.

To clarify it further, I want it to be like this.

```
1. %sitename -> mysite
2. %siteurl -> mysite.com
```

Is there anyway I can do this? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply this to the content of a post you can try something like this:

```
function make_post_tags($content)
{
    $what = array('%sitename', '%siteurl');
    $with = array(
        get_bloginfo('name'),
        get_bloginfo('url'),
    );
    return str_repalce($what, $with, $content);
}

add_filter('the_content', 'make_post_tags', 100, 1);
```